# Logout back en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto con laravel 6, establecí el middleware auth para las rutas con reservadas pero cuando cierro sesion al dar back me permite ver el contenido de la pagina, alguna posible solucion a esto?

Comment: Es la caché de navegador, también sucedería si buscas la página en el historial de navegación. Pero no serán datos actualizados. Prueba recargar la página después de dar back... Puedes agregar los headers correspondientes a los responses `return Response::view('alguna_vista')->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');` o crearte un middleware que se los aplique a las rutas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es la caché de navegador, también sucedería si buscas la página en el historial de navegación. Pero no serán datos actualizados.

[Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

**Prevención de almacenamiento en caché**
Para desactivar el almacenamiento en caché, puede enviar el siguiente encabezado de respuesta.

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

Puedes agregar los headers correspondientes a los responses

```
return Response::view('alguna_vista')->header('Cache-Control', 'no-store, no-cache, private, must-revalidate');
```

O Laravel trae un Middleware [`SetCacheHeaders`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/SetCacheHeaders.html) para manejar los headers de cache. Incluso [está disponible](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/c78a1d8184f00f8270d8a135cc21590837b6bfbd/app/Http/Kernel.php#L57) sin que tengas que agregarlo a `/app/Http/Kernel.php`

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    //...
    'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
    // ...
];
```

Entonces tendrías que simplemente aplicárselo a las rutas que quieras proteger.

```
Route::get('/', 'AlgunController@index')
    ->middleware('cache.headers:no-store,no-cache,private,must-revalidate;etag');
```

**Directivas**
*Cacheabilidad*

`private`: Indica que la respuesta está destinada a un único usuario y no debe almacenarse en un caché compartido. Un caché privado puede almacenar la respuesta.

`no-cache`: Obliga a los cachés a enviar la solicitud al servidor de origen para su validación antes de liberar una copia en caché.

*Revalidación y recarga*

`must-revalidate`: El caché debe verificar el estado de los recursos obsoletos antes de usarlo y los caducados no deben usarse.

*Otros*

`no-store`: El caché no debe almacenar nada sobre la solicitud del cliente o la respuesta del servidor.

Comment: Gracias amigo, cree un middleware para borrar el cache y funciono de esta forma, mil gracias

Comment: Vale, genial. También puedes crealo tú mismo, es como se hace artesanalmente, este middleware SetCacheHeaders lo encontré ahora gracias a tu pregunta, no sé a partir de que versión lo agregaron pero lo probé en la 5.8 y funciona.

Answer (score 0):

> Los grupos de **middleware** pueden asignarse a rutas y acciones de
>   controlador utilizando la misma sintaxis que el **middleware**
>   individual. Una vez más, los grupos de middleware hacen que sea más
>   conveniente asignar muchos **middleware** a una ruta a la vez

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

}
```

o

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->flush();

    $request->session()->regenerate();

    return redirect('/login');
}
```

Comment: mis rutas ya tienen el middleware de auth, pero cuando cierro sesion y doy atras de permite ver, si quiero acceder desde url me retorna al login en caso de no estar logueado pero dando atras me deja ingresar

Comment: lo que puedes retornar es a una ruta de inicio general no un back si no una **redirect url('home')**

Comment: si ya lo tiene, apenas cierro sesion me manda al home pero di doy atras me deja ver el contenido, obviamente ya no puedo realizar operaciones en este lado pero si me permite visualizar

Comment: muestra el codigo como lo tienes?

Comment: ya lo solucione creando este middleware   public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        header('Last-Modified:' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . 'GMT');
        header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        return $next($request);
    }