# Logout Laravel 6.x No cierra sesion. con metodo de logout Auth::logout y ruta logout

Tags: laravel-5, php7, login

me encuentro con un problema relacionado con el paquete de autenticacion ,el cual, cuando se quiere cerrar la sesión, lo único que se obtiene es que se redireccione a la pagina de login, pero al retroceder en el navegador, se vuelve a la sesión anterior. Dejo el código que tengo en los controladores y los middleware que utilizo. 
Esto se encuentra en la carpeta Auth generada por el paquetes

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except(['logout']);
    }
```

La referencia al metodo indicado en la documentacion lo realizo en otro formulario y el siguiente:

```
  <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
       @csrf
  </form>
```

La unica manera que funciona o realiza lo que se espera, es cuando se realiza una limpieza de cache desde el navegador.

Comment: Si al acceder a la ruta 'logout', se ejecuta el código `Auth::logout()`, cuando el usuario "retrocede en el navegador", en realidad no se vuelve a la sesión anterior, es solo el navegador que muestra lo que ha almacenado en caché de las visitas a páginas anteriores. El usuario no podrá navegar ni interactuar con nada que requiera que inicie sesión porque en el servidor no estará autenticado.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Pero hay alguna manera para evitar que al retroceder , no "Ingrese" y se quede en el login del sistema?

Comment: Desde Laravel creo no mucho, podrías agregar header a las respuestas para indicarle al navegador que no guarde las páginas en cache como está explicado [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/329008/92278), pero eso también va a hacer que tu sitio sea más lento, porque cada página que se visite va a tener que cargar todo desde cero, hasta el más mínimo icono.

Comment: Si no, puedes probar con algo de javascript en la página del login como está explicado [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/2168/92278) pero no creo que sea garantía de que funcione si un usuario con suficientes conocimientos técnicos quiere eludirlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba agregando este método al controlador que utilices para generar la vista que no quieres que se vea si ya has cerrado la sesión

```
public function __construct(){
   $this->middleware('auth');
}
```

Lo que hará será comprobar que hayas iniciado sesión correctamente, y al detectar que no has iniciado sesión de redigirá al login